# Por que esta función no devuelve correctamente el valor ? PHP

Tags: php, html

Estoy bastante desesperado por que por mas que intento no consigo que este login muestre el bloque correcto cuando el usuario y la contraseña son correctas, he probado a ejecutarlo sin comprobación y todo funcionaba por lo que asumo que el fallo tiene que estar en la función que realiza la comprobación `comprobarUsuario()` pero no encuentro que podría estar saliendo mal.

**CODIGO PHP**

```
 <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <?php
    function compruebaTexto($campo){
        $aux=$GLOBALS['data'];

        if(!isset($aux[$campo])){
            $aux="";
        }else{
            $aux=$aux[$campo];
        }
        return textoAlfanumerico($aux);
    }
    
    function compruebaArray($array){
        $aux=$GLOBALS['data'];

        if(!isset($aux[$array])){
            $array=[];
        }else{
            $array=$aux[$array];
        }
        return $aux;
    }

    function textoAlfanumerico($variable){
        if(!is_array($variable)){
            return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/',"",$variable);
        }
        $arrayAux=[];
        foreach($variable as $clave=>$valor){
            $arrayAux[$clave]=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/',"",$valor);
        }
        return $arrayAux;
    }
    
    $tablaUsuarios=[
        'admin'=>'1234',
        'david'=>'david',
        'angela'=>'angela'
    ];
    
        
    function comprobarUsuario(){
        
        if (isset($GLOBALS['data'])){
            $_usuario=compruebaTexto('usuario');
            $_pass=compruebaTexto('pass');

            //Tengan un minimo de caracteres
            if (strlen($_usuario)>3 && strlen($_pass)>3){
                foreach($GLOBALS['tablaUsuarios'] as $regUser=>$regPass){
                    //Comprobamos usuario y contraseña
                    if ($regUser == $_usuario && $regPass == $_pass)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if(!comprobarUsuario()) { ?>
        
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
            Usuario: <input type="text" name="usuario"><br>
            Contraseña: <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
            
        </form>
   
    <?php } else { ?>
      
    <?php
    
    if($_POST){
        $data=$_POST;
    }elseif($_GET){
        $data=$_GET;
    }; 

    $usuario= compruebaTexto('usuario');
    $pass= compruebaTexto('pass');

    $datosUsuario= <<< HTML
        Usuario: $usuario<br>
        Password: $pass<br>
    HTML;

    echo $datosUsuario;

    ?>

    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

El problema es que ponga lo que ponga en los campos del formulario aunque coincidan con los que figuran en el array de `$tablaUsuarios` siempre ejecuta la sentencia `if` y nunca el `else` que debería aparecer cuando coinciden los campos con el array.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: entonces el problema de lógica esta en `comprobarUsuario`, has verificado que esta condicion se cumpla `strlen($_usuario)>3 && strlen($_pass)>3` ?

Comment: verifica en que momento se cumple esta condición tambien: `isset($GLOBALS['data'])` ? la verdad no me queda claro por que te falta código y no puedo reproducir el error...

Comment: ```isset($GLOBALS['data'])``` Debería cumplirse en el momento en el que se rellenan los campos del formulario, antes de introducir la nueva función se cumplía de esta manera y la longitud de los campos también se cumple. :(

Comment: es que no veo en ingun sitio que hayas declarado `$GLOBALS['data'];` seguro no lo eliminaste en el momento que agregaste algo...

Comment: Estaria definido despues del ```else if($_POST){
        $data=$_POST;
    }elseif($_GET){
        $data=$_GET;
    };``` Debería definirlo antes ? Pero en caso de hacerlo antes no sabría si el método es post o get puesto que esta en el formulario, no ?

Comment: hasle un `var_dump($GLOBALS['data'])` dentro de la funcion `comprobarUsuario` a ver que te sale.

Comment: Aparece como Undefined. "Notice: Undefined index: data in E:\Xampp\htdocs\Work\index.php on line 47
NULL."
Pero si defino la variable antes de la función, al principio del código entonces siempre muestra el apartado "else" con los valores admin y 1234. Que es el primer clave => valor del array de usuarios.

Comment: entonces hay esta el error nunca recibe el dato por algún motivo... verifica la declaración y verifica que sea accesible dentro del a funcion ... de lo contrario siempre será `null` y siempre entrara en el ultimo `return false`.... y por ende en el siguiente `!(false) == true` y en el código nunca entrara al `else`, el problema es de lógica.

Comment: Muchas gracias !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Aparece como Undefined. "Notice: Undefined index: data in
> E:\Xampp\htdocs\Work\index.php on line 47 NULL." Pero si defino la
> variable antes de la función, al principio del código entonces siempre
> muestra el apartado "else" con los valores admin y 1234. Que es el
> primer clave => valor del array de usuarios.

según lo comentado: entonces hay esta el error, nunca recibe el dato por algún motivo... verifica la declaración y verifica que sea accesible dentro de la funcion ... de lo contrario siempre será `null` y siempre entrara en el ultimo `return false`.... y por ende en el siguiente `!(false) == true` siempre evaluara true y en el código nunca entrara al `else`, el problema es de lógica.

dentro de `comprobarUsuario` debes cumplir el escenario donde `$GLOBALS['data']` existe y tiene valor; de lo contrario no entrar en el ultimo `else`.